# Extract data from a txt file on python

Tags: python, regex

I`m in a need to extract Insta profile names from a lot of text files.
The profiles names have some variations as we can see below and are inside a lot of text:

```
@profilename 
insta: profile_name 
Ig: profilename
IG: profilename
ig: profile.name
Instagram: @profile.name
Instagram @profilename
IG profilename
Insta: profile_name
Insta: profilename
https://instagram.com/profilename
IG @profilename
Ig: _profilename_
Instagram  : profilename
Ig profile_name
IG >> profilename
stagram: profilename
ig @ _.profile.name.__
INSTAGRAM acc: profile_name
Ig: ____profilename____
IG: @profile.name
```

I'm using python and I don't know how to scrape only the requested data. 
We have space before 
and after a profile name(It's the only common for all pns)

How is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful?

```
@\S+|(?<=:\s).+|(?<=ig\s)\w+|(?<=com/).+|(?<=@\s).+|(?<=>>\s).+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OjrVbk/1)

This covers (brute-forces?) all the possible variations that are described above in the question. Maybe this is not the most efficient way though, would be interesting to see what others come up with.

**Regex Explanation:**

```
@\S+          Match profilename after @
|             or
(?<=:\s).+    Match profilename after : + space
|             or
(?<=ig\s)\w+  Match profilename after ig + space OR IG + space (enable case insensitive flag -i)
|             or
(?<=com/).+   Match profilename after com/
|             or
(?<=@\s).+    Match profilename after @ + space
|             or
(?<=>>\s).+   Match profilename after >> + space
```

[image]

Comment: Work like a charm for most of cases, but for (?<=:\s).+, I`m in an issue where every time a : is found, the next word is grabbed. Is it possible to tune it to match only the profiles. ig, insta…?

Comment: @F.Costa ugly, but would work https://regex101.com/r/OjrVbk/3

Comment: But works. :) Tks.